# Use Cordova with Webkit instead of the native engine

Tags: windows, cordova, internet-explorer, webkit, crosswalk-runtime

I'm building a Cordova app for Windows 8, and I'm blocked by the limitations of Internet Explorer. (I use things that work on Firefox and Chrome, and not IE; and I'm spending too much time trying to fix them)

I've heard there is a way to tell Cordova to use webkit instead of the native rendering engine. But I'm looking around and I don't see much anything. Does anyone know about it ?

The closest I've found is the [Crosswalk project](https://crosswalk-project.org/), however the plugin doesn't exist for Windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: To my opinion CrossWalk is the only solution out there at this moment